# Changing tabs and landing back on the same tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-tabs

Ok, I do not have code for this so I would need assistance here. I have a page that has multiple tabs worth of information. If I proceed to an entirely new page (URL) and then hit back on the browser, is there a way to land back on the tab I left off of?

Comment: browser by default do the same

Comment: its completely dependent of tech you are using.. and to code for that

Comment: If I am on tab 4 and proceed to another page, when I click back I want to be on Tab 4, not Tab 1.

How would I do this in JS

Answer (score 0):

when you click on a tab you can append a url parameter e.g. `?tab=tab1`. And when you load the page you can check you're url parameters and default to that tab if it is in the parameter.

Here's an example that's similar. When you click on the toolbar on the left on bootstrap's getting started page it appends that item to the url. so when i click on 'support' the url looks like http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support and when you go to that url it automatically scrolls you to that section on the page.

Comment: If I am on tab 4 and proceed to another page, when I click back I want to be on Tab 4, not Tab 1. How would I do this in JS